# How do I sanitize CSV input with the CsvReader?

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

I'm using the [CsvReader](http://sql.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) library in my Windows Forms application, which is coded in horribly messy VB (I've recently taken over the project.)

I'm currently capable of reading semi-colon separated files without quoting, but I'm having  a problem: most of the input has quoted fields, but includes unescaped quote characters within the fields.

I cannot change the input, so I must tackle it somehow. One solution would be to entirely disable quoting -- but I'm not quite sure how to do that...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've only played a little with this library [LINQtoCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx), but I think it may help with quoted fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Answer (score 0):

How generic do you need it to be?
It is quite simple to write your own CSV parser that reads the data into a DataTable.

In some cases parsing the csv file can be as simple as doing a `File.ReadAllLines(filename)` and then for each line doing a `string.Split` using a semicolon as the separator to get the columns. 
Your code will probably be more advanced than that, but if you have specific needs writing it yourself is probably a good idea.